# jQuery ajax only updating div once

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am currently playing around with ajax trying to create a script that returns a value from a database that updates in realtime.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-gb">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            liveReload('#ajax');
        });
    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <section id="ajax">0</section>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

class Ajax
{
    public static function grab()
    {
        try
        {
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ajax', 'root', null);
            $rq = $db->query('select setting, value from test');
            return $rq->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)[0];
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode(Ajax::grab());
```

**JQUERY**

```
(function() {

liveReload = function(element) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            $(element).html(data['value']);
            setTimeout(liveReload, 1000);
        }
    })
}

})(jQuery);
```

The problem is that this value is only being updated in the page once despite the function returning the new values as they are updated.

Comment: Tried that but the same thing happens.

Comment: Why would you put the function into an immediately executed closure if you then use the global variable `liveReload`? Can you please also show how you call the function for the first time? Anyway, you don't pass the `element` into setTimeout, so it looses the reference to the element and effectively shows nothing

Comment: Try to call the function again in the success block

Comment: @devnull69 yeah that's probably right, to be sure we need to see the first function call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comment: you don't pass the element into setTimeout, so it looses the reference to the element and effectively shows nothing

```
setTimeout(function() {liveReload(element);}, 1000);
```

Comment: I believe this is probably the problem :) Also, you can do
 `liveReload.bind(this,element)` instead of `function() {liveReload(element);}`

Comment: Thanks, this works well. I am new to jQuery so i am bound to make a few silly mistakes.